# How to get the modify column or update statement in sqlalchemy event "after_update"

Tags: python-2.6

Excuse me, I used the SQLAlchemy event to listen to after_update, but need to get the update statement, or which fields have been updated this time, what method can I get?

I checked the official documentation, but I didn't find any instructions for getting the update column, or updating the statement. I didn't find the relevant information when I searched.

looking forward for the help

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did in my project and it worked:

```py
import json

from sqlalchemy import event, inspect


def update_instance_log(mapper, connection, target):
    "listen for the 'after_update' event"

    # this will return a dict with keys of mutated columns and values before update
    old_values = inspect(target).committed_state
    
    # from the old_values above, get the same dict but with updated values
    new_values = {key: inspect(target).dict[key] for key in old_values.keys()}

    table = models.MyLogClass.__table__
    connection.execute(table.insert().values(
      OldValue=json.dumps(old_values),
      NewValue=json.dumps(new_values),
      # ... other values
    ))


event.listen(MyClass, 'after_update', update_instance_log)
```